# X509 Decoder tool based on Certificate schema file

Tags: x509, asn.1

I am looking for a tool which is capable to decode X509 Certificated where additional Extensions are also added according to a predefined schema.

Similar to this. I assume if it is the typical notation for the schema, then someone must have implemented a generic parser for that.

```
FooProtocol DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

    FooQuestion ::= SEQUENCE {
        trackingNumber INTEGER(0..199),
        question       IA5String
    }

    FooAnswer ::= SEQUENCE {
        questionNumber INTEGER(10..20),
        answer         BOOLEAN
    }

    FooHistory ::= SEQUENCE {
        questions SEQUENCE(SIZE(0..10)) OF FooQuestion,
        answers   SEQUENCE(SIZE(1..10)) OF FooAnswer,
        anArray   SEQUENCE(SIZE(100))  OF INTEGER(0..1000),
        ...
    }

END
```

or real life example for a given Object ID extension

```
boot_seq := SEQUENCE
{
    certType INTEGER, -- indicates certificate type
    bootCore INTEGER, -- indicates the core in the device that needs to be booted
    bootCoreOpts INTEGER, -- Configuration options for the core being booted
    destAddr OCTET STRING, -- Load address
    imageSize INTEGER -- image size
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the tools that are capable of compiling ASN.1 schemas into data bindings in a variety of languages and platforms: https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Heimdal](https://github.com/heimdal/heimdal) in its master branch has an open source ASN.1 compiler that understands a subset of X.681/X.682/X.683 extensions and can actually fully decode a `Certificate`, including every kind of `Attribute`, `Extension`, and `OtherName` declared in `lib/asn1/rfc2459.asn1` (and you can add more, rebuild, and use it).

It also can transliterate DER to JSON (but it's not X.697 JER compliant), so you can run `asn1_print /path/to/DER/file Certificate` and you'll get a beautiful JSON representation of the complete certificate, including all the attributes, extensions, and `otherName` SAN types that are declared in `lib/asn1/rfc2459.asn1`.